# After restoring GitLab backup, new SSH public keys randomly supersede other users' existing keys

Tags: ssh-keys, gitlab

This occurred with a new (not upgraded) installation of GitLab 8.6.4.

I installed GitLab and my team evaluated it. Of course I and others entered our SSH public keys.

As part of our evaluation I made a GitLab backup and restored it.

After I restored the backup, new user Shung Wang entered his SSH public key.

Now, whenever I try to access the git repositories via SSH, the server thinks I am Shung Wang.  For example, when I tested my SSH connection from my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, I got this:

`ssh -T git@gitserver
Welcome to GitLab, Shung Wang!`

As a second test, I tried to clone a private repository to which Shung did not have access:

`git clone git@gitserver:sw/devops.git
Cloning into 'devops'...
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Then I made Shung a member of the devops project, and `git clone` succeeded.  I really am accessing GitLab repositories as Shung Wang.

Obviously this is a most unsatisfactory security situation.  How can I access GitLab repositories as myself other than Shung Wang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

GitLab maintains file `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, in which it gives each SSH public key names `key-1`, `key-2`, and so on.

Upon backup restore, the name gets reset to `key-1`, so subsequent keys have duplicate names.  Here is my `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file showing my key and Shung Wang's key both named `key-1`:

```
# Managed by gitlab-shell
command="/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-1",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAA...2SkSQ== jm...@wavecomp.com
###################################################################################################################################################################################
#####################################################################################################################################################################################
command="/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-1",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAA...nKQ== wang....@wavecomp.com
...
```

Apparently the last occurrence of `key-1` is used for both me and Shung.

I reported this GitLab bug in [GitLab issue 1263](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1263).

### Workarounds

Until the bug is fixed, users can try these workarounds.

#### Workaround 1

Use `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:shell:setup` to [rebuild the `authorized_keys` file](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/maintenance.html#rebuild-authorized_keys-file)

#### Workaround 2

I recommend trying workaround 1 first.

The following is what I actually did myself before discovering workaround 1.

1. After you restore a backup, log in as some existing  user and register a new SSH public key
2. Search file `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` for `key-1`.  If you find two, you have the problem described above.
3. Those lines of `######...` are not decoration.  They are keys that were deleted by users.  When a key is deleted, GitLab replaces every character in it with a `#`, presumably so the remaining keys do not move around in the file.  Replace all characters in all SSH keys created before the backup restore with the `#` character in a fashion similar to what you see in the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` shown above.
4. Tell all your users they must re-enter their SSH public keys.  If they complain, remind them to be thankful that the rest of the backup worked.

Rather than all that tedious editing in step 3, I suspect that you can simply move file `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` aside and replace it with an empty file, and then tell everyone to re-enter their SSH public keys.  However I did not try this myself.  If this works for you, please tell us in a comment.